# 403 FORBIDDEN in django agon-rating

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have `403 FORBIDDEN` error in [agon-ratings](https://github.com/eldarion/agon-ratings) plugin when submit rating.
I have read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax). But csrf token exists in header:

```
Request Headersview source  
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  22
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  csrftoken=6C7zHmrBufWbiYeTXwRkCWC9hDfdxGoW;    sessionid=4d6b6977721fcb97f6903d0aaab5e632
Host    localhost:8000
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost:8000/news/40/asdas/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/23.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing a post via ajax request, if thats correct than you need to send the csrf token as part of POST data or via the X-CSRFToken header.

I dont see any of that in the request header you posted.

Django docs you linked have a working example about how to do this (and if you use jQuery its mostly a copy and paste job)

Comment: still your request does not show csrf header or data; maybe you can post the relevant js code you have

Comment: now: X-CSRFToken 6C7zHmrBufWbiYeTXwRkCWC9hDfdxGoW, but still "forbidden"

Comment: have a look at django.middleware.csrf in process_view and do some debugging there (print / pdb.set_trace() ...) to find out where the request gets marked as forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST method. And with POST method, you need to write {% csrf_token %} in HTML  inside form element or pass csrftoken in ajax request i.e https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/.

It is compulsory when you write CSRFMiddleware and csrf context processor in your django settings.